# How to use webpack-dev-server with multiple webpack configs?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Imagine I have a project like this:

```
/moduleA/src...
/moduleB/src...
/mainApp/src...
```

I have a separate webpack.config for each module and the main app.  The modules are libraries and the main app imports those libraries.

Is it possible to configure webpack-dev-server to serve all three?

What I want to avoid is having to stop the dev server, rebuild moduleA and moduleB, and restart the dev server, every time I want to make a change to moduleA or B.

Comment: I am facing very similar issue right now. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with `webpack-dev-server` only because that tool is built to watch and serve a single webpack **application** configuration only.

So the high level answer is: run `webpack-dev-server` for the application and a watcher for each package dependency, at the same time. A rebuild by one of the watchers will cause a subsequent rebuild of the application by webpack.

I recommend if you are not already managing your packages within a monorepo that you do so, because it makes this all *a little bit* less ugly.

Assumptions:

- packages are managed within a monorepo using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)
- each package (and the application) has a `webpack.config.js`
- you are using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)

Steps:

1. for each dependency package, e.g. `moduleA`:

   - install [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

     ```
     yarn add cross-env
     ```
   - set up webpack as a watcher in development mode by adding `watch` to the config:

     ```
     watch: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
     ```
   - add an NPM script `"start:dev"`:

     ```
     "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js"
     ```
2. for the application package, e.g. `mainApp`:

   - install [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

     ```
     yarn add cross-env
     ```
   - add an NPM script `"start:dev"`:

     ```
     "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js"
     ```
3. in the monorepo root:

   - install [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

     ```
     yarn add concurrently
     ```
   - add the NPM scripts* for calling the application and each dependency package's `"start:dev"` and a `"start:dev"` which uses them:

     ```
     "watch:app": "cd packages/mainApp && npm run start:dev",
     "watch:moduleA": "cd packages/moduleA && npm run start:dev",
     "watch:moduleB": "cd packages/moduleB && npm run start:dev",
     "start:dev": "
         concurrently
             \"npm run watch:app\"
             \"npm run watch:moduleA\"
             \"npm run watch:moduleB\"
     "
     ```

Steps to run (in the root of the monorepo):

1. [bootstrap](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/bootstrap) your monorepo with lerna:

   ```
   lerna bootstrap
   ```
2. start the app dev server and watchers for all of the dependency packages:

   ```
   npm run start:dev
   ```
3. navigate to your application dev server endpoint, e.g. `localhost:8080`

___

Addendum: if a monorepo is out of the question, you can look at a combination of using [`yarn link`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link) and an NPM script in your application's `package.json` that looks something like*:

```
{
    "start:dev": "
        concurrently
            \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js\" 
            \"cd ./node_modules/moduleA && npm run start:dev\"
            \"cd ./node_modules/moduleB && npm run start:dev\"
     "
}
```

___

*Note: newlines within NPM scripts are added for readability; you must collapse the newlines if you use these in your `package.json`.