# Single Webpack Dev Server instance for multiple dynamically added projects

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was wondering if something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444931/how-to-use-webpack-dev-server-with-multiple-webpack-configs) is possible. I am facing very similar issue right now and don't know how to deal with it.

To be more precise, I have a few projects like this:

```
projA/src/
projB/src/
projC/src/
```

each of them has separate webpack.config file and **each of them is an independent project**.

Is it possible to configure Webpack to serve all of them simultaneously?

Now, I want to add another project and have them like this:

```
projA/src/
projB/src/
projC/src/
projD/src/
```

`projD` is another independent project with its own webpack.config file.

Is it possible to add it without restarting the Webpack Dev Server?

Comment: Perhaps my answer on the other Q can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444931/how-to-use-webpack-dev-server-with-multiple-webpack-configs/56391987#56391987

Comment: @sdgluck Thanks for a suggestion. What I need is slightly different. I would like to have for example 3 independent applications which are served on different endpoints by single webpack instance. And then, I'd like to dynamically (without reloading webpack) add another project to the single webpack instance. Is that even possible with webpack?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek were you ever able to figure out how to do this?

Comment: @cjones26 No, unfortunately. I didn't find a way to do this and dropped the idea altogether.